# NFS async mode causes inotify to fire multiple CLOSE_WRITE events

Tags: nfs, inotify

I have a nfs server and a client (v4, both CentOS 7.6/7.8)
On the server I have a program which uses `inotifywait` to copy away incoming files (on `CLOSE_WRITE`)

On the client the share is mounted like
`sudo mount 192.168.1.10:/myshare /mnt/share` (this implies async mode)
or
`sudo mount -o sync 192.168.1.10:/data/shares/myshare /mnt/share`

*Explanation of sync*

> If the sync option is specified on a mount point, any system call that writes data to files on that mount point causes that data to be flushed to the server before the system call returns control to user space. This provides greater data cache coherence among clients, but at a significant performance cost.

On the server I watch the folder `/data/shares/myshare` like
`inotifywait -m -e CLOSE_WRITE /data/shares/myshare | while read path action file; do echo "$action"; done`

Now I copy a big enough file (effect starts at approx. 500mbyte) with a normal `cp`

**Problem**
What happens on the server is that with the `sync` flag the event `CLOSE_WRITE` is triggered one time when the file has been copied, which is the desired effect.
But in async mode the event is triggered multiple times and since we use this event to copy away the incoming files on the server, we copy incomplete files.

While using the sync flag solves the problem per se, it introduces a big performance hit of approx. 25% - 35% with my 580mbyte testfile (it seems to get less with bigger files and got even as fast as async with a 2.5gbyte file)

The problem doesnt occur with samba, so I think the problem is nfs related.

Are there any flags/options or other possibility to maintain performance while not triggering the event multiple times?